# How to use Rewrite.config rules from code behind

Tags: c#, xml, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to apply the rules that are configured in my rewrite.config to a certain text with urls inside, so if I have a text with a link inside "my example link http://www.contoso.com/hi" I want to process the text, apply the rules written in the configuration file so I get "my example link http://www.contoso.com/bye"

I have started a XML parser but I think is a lot of work, is there any class in the .NET framework that deals with all of these "{R:1}", also I am wondering how people unit tests all these rules...